# Full outer join tables on one or other column using OR in ON clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to do a full outer join on 2 tables -  Table_A and Table_B on 2 columns Unique_ID1 OR Unique_ID2 -as some rows may match on one and others on another and I have no way to determine this.

I tried this -

```sql
Select *
from Table_A 
     full outer join Table_B on Table_A.Unique_ID1 = Table_A.Unique_ID1
                             OR  Table_A.Unique_ID2 = Table_A.Unique_ID2
```

While this gives me no error, the query runs forever. What is the best way to re-structure this to get the desired output?

Comment: `Table_A.Unique_ID1 = Table_A.Unique_ID1`? The  only time `Table_A.Unique_ID1` would not equal the value of itself is when it has the value `NULL`. The same for your clause `Table_A.Unique_ID2 = Table_A.Unique_ID2`. Seems like you qualified the columns with the wrong name on one side of the boolean expression. It's times like this where *good* aliasing really helps too.

Comment: Sorry I meant to write this- Table_A.Unique_ID1 = Table_B.Unique_ID1
                             OR  Table_A.Unique_ID2 = Table_B.Unique_ID2

Comment: You should ask a new question with sample data and desired results.  A `full outer join` with `or` seems highly unlikely as the best way to do something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the query you actually were intending to run:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table_A a
FULL OUTER JOIN Table_B b
    ON a.Unique_ID1 = b.Unique_ID1 OR a.Unique_ID2 = b.Unique_ID2;
```

That being said, if you still have performance problems with the above, then adding indices might be in order here.  The `ON` clause of your query is actually a bit tricky to index.  You could rewrite the query as a union:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table_A a
FULL OUTER JOIN Table_B b ON a.Unique_ID1 = b.Unique_ID1
UNION
SELECT *
FROM Table_A a
FULL OUTER JOIN Table_B b ON a.Unique_ID2 = b.Unique_ID2;
```

Then add the following indices:

```
CREATE INDEX idx1 ON Table_A (Unique_ID1);
CREATE INDEX idx2 ON Table_A (Unique_ID2);
CREATE INDEX idx1 ON Table_B (Unique_ID1);
CREATE INDEX idx2 ON Table_B (Unique_ID2);
```

While my union version might not logically be identical to your current query, you can probably tweak it to make it so.  And, it is likely to be sargable, with both halves of the union using an index.

Answer (score 0):

Your condition always evaluated to true since you have the column from `Table_A` in both sides of the equality check, producing a full Cartesian product. Replace one side of the equality with `Table_B`, and you should be OK:

```sql
SELECT          *
FROM            Table_A 
FULL OUTER JOIN Table_B ON Table_A.Unique_ID1 = Table_B.Unique_ID1 OR
-- Here ----------------------------------------------^
                           Table_A.Unique_ID2 = Table_B.Unique_ID2
-- And here ------------------------------------------^
```